# What is the best way to send data to PC from "MCU + Wifi Module"?

Tags: module, wifi

I don't know anything about wireless protocols. With this quick setup i want to get inside. I just want to write a windows desktop application which receives only a couple of bytes of data from a mcu+wifi module "NodeMCU" which is connected to the same router. I can write a simple desktop app with visual studio. But sending data over ip has many methods as far as i read.

What is the simplest way to achieve? (I'm experienced in STM32 mcu's and electronics except internet protocols.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send the data from the embedded board (with the mcu) to a TTL-To-WiFi module. Then from your PC application you should open a socket and connect to the module IP to listen in the correct port the data from your board.. There are a lot of module in the market used as "bridge" or converter: you have only to setup in it the local IP address, the destination IP (your PC) and the TCP port where you want to send data. From point of view of the board you use a standard USART and the message is sent to the destination IP. In your PC application you should be able to create a socket and connect it to the wi-fi module.